# Combining zsh’s tab completion with case insensitivity

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have zsh 5.0.7 configured to use case-insensitive tab completion with

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

The problem I’m having is that this case insensitivity often leads to my needing to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> an extra time. For example, my home directory contains the folders “Desktop”, “Documents”, and “Downloads”. If I’m in my home folder and I type

```
cd D
```

and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I see the three possibilities listed for me. On the other hand, if I type

```
cd d
```

and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then the “d” changes to “D” but I don’t see the completion menu; I need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again for that to happen. Is there a way to get the completion menu at the same time that the “d” is changed to a “D”?

Comment: do you have the menucomplete option enabled?

Comment: @llua No, I didn’t. That seems to be what I want. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enabling the option `MENU_COMPLETE` will skip the correction and immediately insert the first possible match.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For those wondering, like I was, the full command is `setopt MENU_COMPLETE`, needs to be placed in `.zshrc`

Answer (score 4):

Another useful setting could be

```
setopt no_list_ambiguous
```

It will correct "c" to "C" *and* show the completion menu.

Answer (score 0):

The OP and the answers didn't work for me. The top answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1092033/how-can-i-make-zsh-tab-completion-fix-capitalization-errors-for-directories-and) works fine:

---

put these lines in your zsh config file, usually `~/.zshrc`:

```zsh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```