# Case-insensitive completion in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, case-sensitivity

I have a folder `~/TestFolder`. The current working directory is the home directory(`~`).

I want to enter a partial command, for example `cd test`, and I want it auto filled to give the command `cd TestFolder` upon pressing Tab.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `cd Test` and then Tab? It may be about case sensitivity. Or do you explicitly want your tab completions to be case-insensitive? What is the shell?

Comment: Tab completion is a feature of your shell (default is `bash` on most Linuxes, `zsh` on up-to-date Macs). But unix-style file and directory names are case sensitive: in a single directory, both `test` and `Test` could exist at the same time, and be two different files or directories. Usually, the shell will not change the case of typed characters on tab-completion, but your shell might have an option to enable it.

Comment: Hi! And welcome here, Dugu02! As the others have pointed out, this is a functionality of the *shell*. We don't know which shell you are using! could you tell us what `echo $SHELL` says?

Comment: I use /bin/bash on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The same applies to filesystems which are case-preserving but not case-sensitive (e.g. many Mac or PC filesystems): even though you can access the folder as `testfolder`, all the shells I tried (`bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `csh`) autocomplete only if you start with the correct case.

Comment: @gidds Zsh can be configured to do case-insensitive completion.

Answer (score 5):

### Bash

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`-file:

`bind -s 'set completion-ignore-case on'`

This enables case-insensitive completion in bash, as explained by Gilles' answer in
[How to make cd arguments case INsensitive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60162/how-to-make-cd-arguments-case-insensitive).

Tested with bash 5.0.17 on Ubuntu 20.04.

### Other options

I have only tested bash and zsh. This is what I found out for other shells:

The other option in the linked answer adds `set completion-ignore-case on` to `inputrc`. That could be used by other shells, too. According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424471/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-and-inputrc) answer, which also talks about whether to use this option with bash.

Therefore, if not using bash, researching your specific shell first is a good idea (unless others will add tested answers for other shells).

### Zsh

`zsh` uses a [different](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/zsh) line editor and not readline/inputrc. On install it gives the option to press `2` to add a recommended `~/.zshrc`, which already includes the following line. It makes the the desired behaviour work out of the box:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-       z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'`

Tested with zsh 5.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

This also might be helpful: [Combining zsh’s tab completion with case insensitivity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185537/combining-zsh-s-tab-completion-with-case-insensitivity?rq=1)